# Raspbian run autostart from startx in /etc/rc.local

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

On my raspberry pi 2, I have the following commands in `/etc/rc.local`, to run at startup:

```
startx
exit 0
```

Following [this tutorial](https://blog.niteoweb.com/raspberry-pi-boot-to-browser/), I put the following lines in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@midori -e Fullscreen -a <MY-WEBSITE>
```

On startup, I expect the pi to start X, and open . It does start X, but it does not open . However, when I type in `startx` from the terminal logged in as pi, it does as I expect.

How can I change this?

Comment: I fixed this by putting `startx` into `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

The way I went about this was by adding

```
startx
```

to the end of `/etc/profile`. Try that instead and you might get a different result, as I think I had a similar problem.

Comment: When I added this, the screen just goes black after the initial text

Comment: I think I may have initially misread your question. You may want to instead of this, run `sudo raspi-config` and use the option "Enable Boot to Desktop". See if that works the way you're expecting.

Comment: I was doing that before, but code put into `/etc/rc.local` would run at the same time X starts. I've been looking for a way to make `/etc/rc.local` run before the X. Any ideas there?